# How do migration operations (eg. AddField) detect if you're applying or reverting a migration?

Tags: django, database-migration, django-migrations

A good example is `django.db.migrations.AddField`.

Let's say I've created a simple migration such as:

```
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = []

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name="foo",
            name="bar",
            field=models.TextField(blank=True, null=True),
        ),
    ]
```

Running the migration would result in the `bar` field being added, and reverting to a previous migration would result in the `bar` field being removed.

However when I look under the hood of the `AddField` class, I don't see the logic for detecting the direction of the applied migration.

```
class AddField(FieldOperation):
    field: Field[Any, Any] = ...
    preserve_default: bool = ...
    def __init__(
        self,
        model_name: str,
        name: str,
        field: Field[Any, Any],
        preserve_default: bool = ...,
    ) -> None: ...
```

I need to create a similar function for collected data that can apply/revert changes based on changes made to the model the data is based on. This function would be used inside migrations in a similar way to `AddField`, and needs to detect whether the user is applying or reverting a migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `migrate` management command will detect if this is a new (i.e. forward) or previous (i.e. backward) migration, and call either the `database_forwards` or `database_backwards` method depending on the direction of the migration. The `Operation` subclass doesn't need to know the direction on init:

```py
class AddField(FieldOperation):
    ...
    def database_forwards(self, app_label, schema_editor, from_state, to_state):
        to_model = to_state.apps.get_model(app_label, self.model_name)
        if self.allow_migrate_model(schema_editor.connection.alias, to_model):
            from_model = from_state.apps.get_model(app_label, self.model_name)
            field = to_model._meta.get_field(self.name)
            if not self.preserve_default:
                field.default = self.field.default
            schema_editor.add_field(
                from_model,
                field,
            )
            if not self.preserve_default:
                field.default = NOT_PROVIDED

    def database_backwards(self, app_label, schema_editor, from_state, to_state):
        from_model = from_state.apps.get_model(app_label, self.model_name)
        if self.allow_migrate_model(schema_editor.connection.alias, from_model):
            schema_editor.remove_field(
                from_model, from_model._meta.get_field(self.name)
            )
```

This is partly explained in the documentation, specifically in [reversing migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#reversing-migrations) and [writing your own migration operations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/migration-operations/#writing-your-own) sections.